# one JList triggering addition of data to another JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener

here is the code, that anyone can run easy and fast, that shows my problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Driver extends JFrame {

    public ArrayList<String> RN = new ArrayList<String>();

    private JPanel contentPane;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Driver frame = new Driver();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Driver() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 605, 497);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        DefaultListSelectionModel m = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
        m.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        m.setLeadAnchorNotificationEnabled(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(26, 133, 538, 133);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(listRN);
        listRN.setSelectionModel(m);
    //  listRN.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());
        listRN.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(26, 296, 538, 133);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);



        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(listPL);
        listPL.setSelectionModel(m);
    //  listPL.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Load");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                RN.add("Ivan");
                RN.add("Gaga");
                RN.add("Dragan");
                for(int i=0;i<RN.size();i++){
                    modelRN.addElement(RN.get(i));
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(386, 58, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         String d = null;

             if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {

                 int index = listRN.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                 System.out.println("clicked on Item " + index);

                  d = listRN.getSelectedValue();

                 modelPL.addElement(d);
                 }

              }


     };


     DefaultListModel<String> modelRN = new DefaultListModel<String>();

     DefaultListModel<String> modelPL = new DefaultListModel<String>();

     JList<String> listRN = new JList<String>(modelRN); 

     JList<String> listPL = new JList<String>(modelPL);

}
```

Its a simple example. Click on Load button and strings are added to first JList. Click on a string in that JList and it is loaded to the second JList, so nothing major. My problem is with the behavior of the JLists after that...when I click on a selection in a Jlist it loads the string to the second Jlist but the selection highlighted jumps to another String...plus when ever i click on a string in the second Jlist it is connected to the first one.

What is my fundamental flaw in understanding JList behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

listPL and listRN should not have the same ListSelectionModel, when you select an item in the first list it's added to the second list and the selected item within it is changed so also the selected item of the first list is changed because they have the same ListSelectionModel.

Comment: thanks man. silly oversight on my part. everything is ok now :)

Comment: @caniaskyouaquestion i'm happy it's working for you.